# unexpected behavior from $.ajaxSetup()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am facing unexpected behavior after implementing Jquery $.ajaxSetup() function.

My $.ajaxSetup is as follows:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    url: brain,
    type: "POST",
    complete: function(e){loading_off()} // turn off loading screen
});
```

For ajax, I practice the following steps:

```
loading_on(); // turn on loading screen

$.ajax({
        data: {
            data: $("form").serializeArray(),
            req: 'search_'
            },
        success: function(e){
            $(".res").html(e);
        },
});
```

What I am expecting is to start loading_on() function before all ajax requests (as I have put the loading_on() function manually everywhere) and once the ajax is complete, loading_off() function would be called.
What I am getting is- if I use $.ajaxSetup(), the loading_on() function triggers... ajax completes... loading_off() function triggers... **Unexpectedly, loading_on() function triggers again**. Even though it has not been called again. This unexpected behavior does not take place if $.ajaxSetup is not used and rather $.ajax is used to handle all.

If anyone know any solution, please advice. I am stuck with a project.
Sorry for long details (I am not very good with explaining).

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code, or a sample website where the code runs?  It seems like there must be some other reason why loading_on() would be fired twice, but it isn't very clear from the code you've given what could be causing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helping attitude and I would love to paste the codes here. But unfortunately, all my ajax functions are dependent on other multiple functions which are dependent on other functions. It would require me to paste 300 (+-) lines of codes to paste here to complete any ajax. I hope, you will understand. Rather my observation is the conflict is with complete: property of ajaxSetup. Could you help me with that. It looks like Jquery logics are having conflict to run ajaxSetup and ajax-complete functions simultaneously.

Comment: I really cannot see any reason why adding the $.ajaxSetup would fire a completely unrelated function.  You don't even call loading_on() inside or near any ajax.  It really doesn't make sense like this - there isn't enough information to help you. $.ajaxSetup can't cause random execution of random code on random unrelated lines.  There has to be some other place where these are related, and that's why we need more code to help.  My first guess is that you are encoutering errors that prevent the execution of parts of your code. Have you checked the console log in the browser when you run this?

Comment: I have checked firebug console and I am not getting any error. But I will keep your words in mind and will attempt to get you more codes here.